# VSCode messes up my shell script indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

Here's a simple shell script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {10..1}
do
  echo $i
  sleep 1
done

echo 'BLAST OFF!'
```

I like an indentation of two spaces.  When I open this in VSCode, it displays correctly.  It detects that it's a shell script and appears (unless I'm misunderstanding) to recognise that I'm using two spaces for indentation:

[image: Status bar shows "Shell Script" and "Spaces: 2".]

This looks right, [reading this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_autodetection).

Before I save the file, it looks like this:

[image]

but afterwards, it looks like this:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding what "Spaces: 2" means?  I always thought it meant it's using 2 spaces to indent, but I'm wondering now if it's saying "a tab is 2 spaces" and is (rather strangely) using 2 tabs to indent, but is then saving as spaces...

(By the way, I've no specific settings for "Shell Script" mode beyond specifying the eol, so I guess it's using its defaults.)

---

**UPDATE:** If I close and reopen the editor after saving, it then says "Spaces: 4" in the status bar, which seems to agree with what I originally understood.

Comment: do you have a formatter for shell scripts enabled? is it formatting on save?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't _think_ I've got a formatter configured; the relevant section of my `settings.json` file is `"[shellscript]": {
    "files.eol": "\n"
  }`.  And yes, I've got it configured to format on save.